# When $R$ is a subring of $R[\alpha]$

Tags: ring-theory

I am reading Artin's Algebra, Section 5 of Chapter 11.  The chapter begins by saying that we want to find a suitable ring extension $R[\alpha]$ that contains $R$ as a subring as well as $\alpha$.  He then proceeds with an example and a generalization of this to create a general ring extension $R[\alpha]$ in which $\alpha$ satisfies a polynomial relation $f(\alpha)=0$ by defining $R[\alpha]$ to be the quotient ring $R[x]/(f)$, where $(f)$ is the principal ideal generated by $f$.  $\alpha$ is identified by the image of $x$ under the quotient transformation.

However, at the of the section it is brought up that we haven't actually shown that $R$ is a subring of $R[\alpha]=R[x]/(f)$, and proceeds to show that in general this isn't true.  The criterion mentioned for $R$ to be a subring of $R[\alpha]=R[x]/f$ is for the restriction of the quotient transformation to constant polynomials, say $\psi: R\rightarrow R[\alpha]$, is an injection. More importantly, that if $\psi$ is not an injection, then there exists no injective ring homomorphism of $R$ into $R[\alpha]$.

Why is this enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that $R\to R[\alpha]$ is supposed to be an inclusion, so $R$ is a subring of $R[\alpha]$. This can fail if setting the polynomial $f$ equal to $0$ ends up "collapsing" $R$ itself a bit. However, just because the induced map $R\to R[x]/(f)$ isn't injective doesn't mean there isn't *any* injective map ...

Let $R=k[x_1,x_2,\cdots]$ be a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables. Let $f(T)=x_1$ be a constant polynomial in $T$, so $R[T]/(f)=R[x_2,x_3,\cdots,T]$ and the induced map $R\to R[T]/(f)$ is not injective (as $x_1\mapsto 0$), however there is clearly an injective map $R\to R[T]/(f)$ where $x_1\mapsto T$ and $x_i\mapsto x_i$ for $i>1$.

Comment: Thank you for the example; the claim he seemed to be making didn't seem correct, but that certainly shows it in the general case.  Do you know if strengthening the hypothesis to say that $f$ is a non-constant polynomials does show this?  This I feel is a reasonable assumption to make since $f$ is only there to introduce a relation for $\alpha$ to fulfill, and constant polynomials don't quite encode information about $\alpha$ and only work to kill elements in $R$.

Comment: Nope, not good enough. For example if $R=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ and $f(T)=2T-1$ then $R[T]/(f)$ is the trivial ring, as $0=2(2T-1)=4T-2=2$ and then $0=2T-1=-1$. Or alternatively we can write $0=(2T-1)^2=4T^2-4T+1=1$, i.e. $0=1$. So obviously there doesn't exist an injective map $R\to R[T]/(f)$ in this case.

Comment: But doesn't the fact that the induced map $R\rightarrow R[T]/(f)$ has non-trivial kernel back up Artin's claim, since $\psi$ is not an injection and there exists no possible injective ring homomorphism (there isn't even an injection as set maps)?

Comment: Let $R$ be a countably infinite direct product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself (addition and multiplication are component-wise), and let $r = (0,1,1,1,...)$.  Let $f(x) = rx - 1$ (here $1 = (1,1,1,...)$). Then $\psi$ kills $(a,0,0,...)$, but I think the map $(a_1,a_2, a_3, \dots) \mapsto (0,a_1,a_2,a_3, \dots) + (f)$ is an injective ring homomorphism.  As far as I know, Artin mostly only worries about adjoining elements to domains, in which case as long as $f$ is nonconstant, $\psi$ will be injective.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a statement of one way to define a subring.  More precisely, the first definition one learns is that if $R$ is a ring, then $S$ is called a subring of $R$ if $S \subseteq R$ and $S$ is a ring in its own right.  (If your definition of rings requires them to have $1$ then an additional requirement for a subring is often that $1_S = 1_R$, but this is irrelevant to the conversation).

Another way to define a subring of $R$ is to say that $S$ is a subring of $R$ if $S$ is a ring and there exists an injective homomorphism $\psi: S \to R$.  (If your definition of rings requires them to have $1$, then it is often required that $\psi(1_S) = 1_R$.)

That is, $S$ is a subring of $R$ according to the second definition if and only if $S$ is isomorphic to some $S'$, which is a subring of $R$ according to the first definition.

The second definition is the one operating here, since as formal objects $R$ is not a subset of $R[x] / (f)$.  But if $\psi: R \to R[x] / (f)$ given by $\psi(r) = r + f$ is injective, then $R$ is a subring of $R[x] / (f)$ according to this second definition.

Comment: I'm not concerned about why $\psi$ being an injection shows that $R$ can be regarded as a subring of $R[\alpha]$.  I'm concerned about why $\psi$ NOT being an injection rules out the existence of any injective ring homomorphisms.

Comment: Ah, yes, then sea turtles' comment is the relevant one here.